# INSERT INTO Access table from CSV file via C# code

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, odbc

i have this table:

```
Items
====
Barcode (text)
Des (text)
Price (double)
```

i made csv file  on `d:\Items.csv`  for fast insert  `(12345,computer,120.44).....`

i try to insert like this (C# WinForm program):

```
Cmd = Conn.CreateCommand();
SQL = @"INSERT INTO Items SELECT * FROM [Text;DATABASE=" + @"d:" + @"\].[Items.txt];";
Cmd.CommandText = SQL;
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but i got 2 error:

```
1. Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

2. The field 'Items.Barcode ' cannot contain a Null value because the Required property for this field is set to True.  Enter a value in this field.
```

how to fix this ?

Comment: What is your `SQL` looks like when you debug it?

Comment: You know you have d:\Items.csv, and in your code you have Items.txt? Does the file exist?

Answer (score 3):

The following C# code works for me. It imports `C:\Users\Public\Items.csv` into a table named [Items] in my Access 2010 database `C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb`. The contents of the CSV file is simply

```
12345,computer,120.44
```

The code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace myDbTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myConnectionString;
            myConnectionString =
                    @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
                    @"Dbq=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;";

            using (var con = new OdbcConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                con.Open();

                using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText =
                            @"INSERT INTO Items " +
                            @"SELECT * FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=NO;IMEX=2;CharacterSet=437;ACCDB=YES;Database=C:\Users\Public].[Items#csv];";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```